# How do you keep FFMPEG / libx264 from producing a high bitrate at the start of the video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, x264

I have noticed that the Linux version of FFMPEG tends to blow its bit budget like a drunken sailor at the very beginning of a video. Is there a way to prevent this and/or suppress it? I looked thru the libx264 options and couldn't find anything.

The Mac/OS-X version does not seem to suffer from this issue.

Please see the following FFMPEG link for more information on this problem.

http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2296&p=6654

Please also compare with this question:

[Video compression with ffmpeg - Constant quality](https://superuser.com/questions/615471/video-compression-with-ffmpeg-constant-quality)

Comment: Can you post the full ffmpeg output for both commands under the 2 OS please ? The only way to have mismatched outputs is probably due to a different x264 version.

Comment: The output and everything is in the ffmpeg.gusari... link. It's really quite voluminous, the result of several days research, I apologize for its length.