# FFMPEG / x264: Single pass: how do you raise start time bitrates?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, mp4, x264

When using single-pass mode with a VBV size specified, libx264 will initially "sandbag" the bitrate, presumably due to lack of evidence (or perhaps even a bug). ([This is an ironic followup to this question, which dealt with overly HIGH initial bitrates with single-pass encoding *sans* a VBV specification](https://superuser.com/questions/963424/how-do-you-keep-ffmpeg-libx264-from-producing-a-high-bitrate-at-the-start-of-t))

Please see the bitrate graphs at the bottom for more information: notice the original dip, followed by an overcorrection ("Hey, I've got some bits left!") before a normalization. Note that this is corrected in the two-pass solution. The lack of the initial I-frame in these two graphs is likely a tool bug (PTS value of the initial I-frame is 0.15 seconds).

***This effect prevents a "split, encode and reassemble" parallel processing of a long asset, as you will get a quality beat at the start of each segment.***

This can be fixed via dual-pass encoding, an unacceptable solution for live streams (although, if parallelized, one could pay the cost of dual pass encoding).

There are two solutions that I would hope for: any assistance would be more than welcome.

1. A single-pass solution where the encoder is told to hold many more frames initially before producing output, thereby reducing the initial sandbag effect
2. A way to perform limited two-pass encoding as a "pipe": full two-pass encoding as a pipe is of course non-sensical, but it should be possible to have "micro passes" where the pass feedback period is something like one second. This is much less ideal than a single-pass solution to get around such a short effect, but would be acceptable if (1) is impossible.

   - Single Pass bitrate graph: note the initial "sandbag dip". Generated with:

> ffmpeg -i 1080-60fps.mp4 -vf "scale=1200:720" -b:v 1000k -bufsize 1000k onepass.mp4

[image]

- Two Pass bitrate graph: this is the near-ideal result. Note that this final form need not be necessary: avoiding the initial sandbag is sufficient. Generated with:

> ffmpeg -i 1080-60fps.mp4 -vf "scale=1200:720" -b:v 1000k -pass 1 -f mp4 /dev/null
>
> ffmpeg -i 1080-60fps.mp4 -vf "scale=1200:720" -b:v 1000k -pass 2 twopass.mp4

[image: Two Pass bitrate graph: this is the expected result]

- Section of the first frame in the single pass encoding

[image]

- Section of the first frame in the two pass encoding

[image]

Comment: Have you tried CRF mode?